# Using the Jade engine on all .jade files regardless of location

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm using Node and the Express framework for my website, but instead of a separate Views folder, I have a site structure where the .jade files could be anywhere within a `static` folder.

What's the simplest way of getting jade to compile the templates if they end in .jade? Do I have to write a middleware function for the regex `\.jade$`? How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use glob.
Pattern will be '**/*.jade' https://www.npmjs.org/package/glob

Answer (score -1):

You need to tell node where the templates can be found.  Typically, this is done like this

```
app.set('views', '/static/views');  // templates are found in /static/views folder
```